# Using Google Admin to view Drive files Domain-wide

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to list all Google Drive files Domain-wide, both users that still work here, and those that have moved on. With that, we can grep the output for certain terms (former customers) to delete customer-related files.

I believe I have a successful way to list all users using the [Admin SDK Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python), since we have only about 200 total users (max is 500). I also have a way to list all files for a user using the Drive REST API's `files.list()` method. **What I need to know is how to impersonate each user iteratively, in order to run the file listing script.**

I have found the blurb `.setServiceAccountUser(someone@domain.com)` but I'm not really sure where to implement this, either in the service account authorization step, or in a separate middle-man script.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/pinoyyid/googleDriveTransferOwnership/blob/master/src/couk/cleverthinking/tof/Main.java

Specifically lines 285-299 which deal with generating a credential for an impersonated user.

```
   GoogleCredential.Builder builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmailAddress)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(f)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SCOPE));
        // if requested, impresonate a domain user
        if (!"ServiceAccount".equals(impersonatedAccountEmailAddress)) {
            builder.setServiceAccountUser(impersonatedAccountEmailAddress);
        }

        // build the Drive service
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null)
                .setApplicationName("TOF")
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(builder.build()).build();
```

This is Java, but should at least tell you what the steps are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [authorization flow for Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Once you create a service account in a GCP project (console.developers.google.com), enable DWD (domain-wide delegation), then authorize that service account in your G Suite admin console, that key can then be used to "impersonate" any account in the G Suite instance:

Create the credentials object from the json file

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    '/path/to/keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)
```

Create a credential that can impersonate user@example.org (could be any user in the domain though)

```
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('user@example.org')
```

Authorize the credential object (i.e. get an access_token)

```
from httplib2 import Http
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
```

Call the Gmail API:

```
from apiclient import discovery
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='user@example.org').execute()
```